# Web Routing Best Practices for Naming urls NOT MVC

Tags: seo, url-routing

Working on routing my site and am wondering what a good standard is for naming regular pages?  I was going to name them like:

```
/Daily-Winners
```

But I want to reserve the - multiword syntax for titles of threads, blog posts, etc., not for regular traffic pages.

Is there a standard or guideline to make this more attractive for SEO?

Especially for acronyms, like SEO:

```
/SEO/mySeoPage
/Search-Engine-Optimization/mySeoPage
```

Better to use full words or the acronym?

TIA

Comment: "But I want to reserve the - multiword syntax for titles of threads, blog posts, etc., not for regular traffic pages" - why? What is the difference between "regular traffic pages" and the other stuff?

Comment: I was working on the assumption that for users who type in pages, keeping them simpler instead of with "-" would be easier.  But then again, who types anymore. :)  And I can always create shortcut routes as well.

Comment: Don't discourage people from "hacking" your URLs manually! Lots of people "remove the last path part" as a "cd .." operation, so you might want to make that work. Either way, just check your 404 (and similar) logs, and you'll notice what people are expecting of your URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, **the more sense an URL makes to a human, the more sense it makes to a search engine, and the higher rank it will get.** For example, compare

```
http://yoursite.com/SEO/tips?id=1
```

to

```
http://yoursite.com/Search-Engine-Optimization/Tips/1
```

Everyone, including search engines, will like the latter better.

Answer (score 2):

Full words is a winner since you'll get more keyword matches.

Regarding regular pages vs article URLs, I don't think it will make any difference (SEO wise) to group them.